Why does `timezone` not work in `sqlmodel`?
I'm using sqlmodel to do sql-orm. I learned from this page and this page, but both failed, the time inserted into the table is anyway utc time, no matter I set timezone True or False. At last I need to set cur_time: str = Field(default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) then everything goes well. But I'm just confused why I can't insert local time with Columns(DateTime(timezone=True))
My code is
from datetime import datetime

from sqlmodel import (
    TIMESTAMP,
    Column,
    DateTime,
    Field,
    Session,
    SQLModel,
    create_engine,
    func,
    text,
)


class Test(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    # 1st page, utc time
    first_time: datetime | None = Field(
        sa_column=Column(
            TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
            nullable=False,
            server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
        )
    )
    # 2nd page, utc time
    second_time: datetime | None = Field(
        sa_column=Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    )
    # datetime.now, local time
    third_time: str = Field(default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


uri = "sqlite:///./test.db"

engine = create_engine(uri, echo=True)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    test = Test(name="test")
    session.add(test)
    session.commit()


And the result is

I'm using sqlmodel 0.0.20, sqlalchemy 2.0.31, python 3.10.12. I tried both on win10 and ubuntu 22.04, and results are the same, things only go well when I use datetime.now().strftime.
On ubuntu, timedatectl's result is
               Local time: Fri 2024-07-19 15:04:41 CST
           Universal time: Fri 2024-07-19 07:04:41 UTC
                 RTC time: Fri 2024-07-19 07:04:42
                Time zone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no


It is considered best practice to store timestamps in UTC, but present them in the local time zone. This is especially true for sqlite, as it does not have a dedicated date, time, datetime or timestamp type. Rather it uses text or numbers depending on your use case. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype for more details.
You will need to convert the timestamp manually to UTC when sending it to the database and then convert it back to the desired timezone when deserialising it. For example:
import pytz
import sqlalchemy.types as types
from sqlmodel import (
    Column,
    DateTime,
    Field,
    SQLModel,
    func,
)

CST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')

class CSTTimestamp(types.TypeDecorator):

    impl = types.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)

    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        assert value.tzinfo is not None
        if dialect.name == 'sqlite':
            # we provide a UTC timezone, but it will get dropped by sqlite
            return value.astimezone(pytz.utc)
        else:
            # other dialects will be able to store the timezone
            return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'sqlite':
            # we explictly store the value as UTC for sqlite, but it
            # has dropped the timezone and we have a naive datetime.
            # So make it timezone aware and convert to the desired
            # timezone.
            assert value.tzinfo is None
            return CST.fromutc(value)
        else:
            # other dialects will keep the timezone, and some will
            # even convert it to your local timezone depending on your
            # connection settings.
            assert value.tzinfo is not None
            return value.astimezone(CST)


class Test(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    dt: datetime = Field(sa_column=Column(
        CSTTimestamp,
        nullable=False,
        server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
    ))


maybe it could work in sqlalchemy, but your code failed on sqlmodel

Oh, yeah. I was in a rush to leave the house and forgot to put the type as an sa_column. I discovered that sqlite, just doesn't handle timestamps very well. Which is understandable as its impossible for the app and the database to be in different timezones -- as they run in the same process. So had to update the type a little bit too.

So strange. I added some print in your code, and found that process_bind_param didn't run, while process_result_value ran, and I added print(CST.fromutc(value)) before return CST.fromutc(value), the print time is right (2024-09-14 10:38:34+08:00), but the value stored in db is still wrong (2024-09-14 02:38:34)

Why is it wrong? It is the same instant in time as your CST datetime, but in UTC. Why does it matter what the datetime in the db is? I thought you only cared about getting the datetime in CST in python.

With respect to process_result_value(), the function is being called on my machine. Given that the datetime in the db is UTC, it is safe to assume it is running. Maybe set cache_ok = False, if you want process_bind_param() to be called EVERY time while debugging.
